# Service Fabric architecture - Ingress gateway for all trafic?

Tags: azure, azure-service-fabric

I have a question regarding Service Fabric Architecture.
Is architecture in my picture below correct? (Is good idea to place "custom ingress gateway" between load balancer and externally exposed Web-Frontends?)

There are many articles on the Internet that internal services in Service Fabric should not be exposed externally. Some articles on the Internet are about ingress Gateway (not only for externally exposed API). Some other articles are about multiple front end web applications without this ingress Gateway...

My targets:
I would like to create mini-applications in one cluster that will be externally accessible.
At the same time, I would like to solve security, caching, sub-domain routing via ingress gateway...

Thank you very much for your opinion

[image]

Comment: This is possible, I've used [traefik](https://docs.traefik.io/v1.7/configuration/backends/servicefabric/)  as reverse proxy for this in the past, but you could write your own. To handle authentication, caching,...

Comment: @Preben Huybrechts Thank you!

Comment: We use Ocelot: https://ocelot.readthedocs.io/en/latest/introduction/bigpicture.html
We bind Ocelot to port 443 and all traffic gets routed through our ocelot service as our gateway. All other microservices are hidden from the public.